# IIS 7.5 redirect certain requests to other server using ip address

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis

Here is a problem I have been struggling with for a while.
I host a website with the address `www.mywebsite.com` in **server I** but the images of the site come from **server II** (ip: 1.2.3.4) so if there are requests such as **www.mywebsite.com/images/123.jpg** I would like to redirect them to the image server(**Server II**).

I would like that requests that contain `(.*jpg.*)` regex will redirect to **Server II**.

1. Using Url rewrite I added a rule:

   ```
   <rewrite>
           <rules>
               <rule name="Ignore images requests" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                   <match url="(.*jpg.*)" />
                   <action type="Rewrite" url="https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/91615172-find-a-lump-on-cats-skin-632x475.jpg" />
               </rule>
           </rules>
       </rewrite>
   ```

It rewrites the request to a static image as you can see, how can I define it to go to **1.2.3.4/images/imagename.jpg**?

The best solution would be if I could just ignore requests containing **jpg** via my host file, is there a way to that?

Comment: Can you please provide samples of your source and destination url for images? It will help me to create proper rule for you

Comment: @VictorLeontyev  I would like that when the url contains jpg the it will redirect the request to the original server.
For example if I have:
`https://styleplace/UserFiles/Entities/TopBanners/top50161616_586.jpg`

Comment: And image is accessible in original server by this url? : `https://1.2.3.4/UserFiles/Entities/TopBanners/top50161616‌​_586.jpg`

Comment: @VictorLeontyev yes

Answer (score 1):

You redirect rule should be like that:

```
<rule name="image redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="(.*?)\.jpg$" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://1.2.3.4/{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />                           
</rule>
```

It will redirect all requests to files with `.jpg` extension to 1.2.3.4 domain
For example:

`http://www.mywebsite.com/dog-1210559_960_720.jpg` to `http://1.2.3.4/dog-1210559_960_720.jpg`

`http://www.mywebsite.com/UserFiles/Entities/TopBanners/top50161616‌​_586.jpg` to `http://1.2.3.4/UserFiles/Entities/TopBanners/top50161616‌​_586.jpg`

Comment: So far it didn't work because I found out I don't have access to the remote server, I try to solve this issue and try again your code.